# woocommerce_single_product_summary hook is not working properly with flatsome theme

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I am trying to add some custom text per products in single product page in woocommerce via

> woocommerce_single_product_summary

hook and due to using flatsome theme above mentioned hook does not work. here is my sample code:

```
function my_custom_text(){
    
    echo "custom text";
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_custom_text');
```

any suggestions is appriciated.

Comment: Check inside the theme if the action is removed somewhere `woocommerce_single_product_summary`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try a higher priority? like 999

OR try this

```
function my_custom_text() {
    echo "Custom text";
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'my_custom_text' );
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried many ways. I also tried overriding price.php file in child theme but result is not what I expected.

Comment: then you may try woocommerce_before_single_product_summary'